# Trying to use BigInt with software Julia

Tags: factorization

I am tryng to factor the number 2^200 with Julia software. But the program displays the result 0 which is not correct. I think that this is due to the fact that I am not using BigInt. How can I use BigInt? Have I to install some particular package?